# How to add scrollbar to celltable

Tags: java, gwt

i have small problem i.e. their is one celltable with lot of data it is placed in popup so the popup height is very large so my problem is i want to add a scrollbar to my celltable so the popup height reduced
                    please help me anyone....

note:-i will try set height for table and popup but their is no result & i am write code in java & gwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use table.setPageSize method to create paging for lots of data.

Or as you want to create scroll with celltable. You can put celltable in a verticalPane and set vertical pane scrollable. Or use scrollpanel to put celltable.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ScrollPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html).

Answer (score 0):

This works. The only thing I don't like is it scroll the table headers out of view also.

```
<td  style='width:320px' >
  <g:ScrollPanel  width="100%" height ="300px">
      <c:CellTable addStyleNames='{style.cellTable}' ui:field='myListField'/>
  </g:ScrollPanel>
</td>
```